# How to determine optimal points on segments to fit dataset

Tags: geometry

I have 2 sets of associated Cartesian coordinate data defining;
1. line segments
2. points.
I need to determine the points on the segments that optimally fit to the relative shape of the points in the second data-set.

The first data-set (D1) includes 2 points for each entry which define the end-points of the segments, of form (s=start, e=end)

```
{[(X1s, Y1s, Z1s), (X1e, Y1e, Z1e)]
 [(X2s, Y2s, Z2s), (X2e, Y2e, Z2e)]
etc.
}
```

The second data-set (D2) includes a single coordinate for each entry, defining the optimal relative shape that the new points should target;

```
{[(X1, Y1, Z1)],
 [(X2, Y2, Z2)],
etc.
}
```

In summary, I must create a new data-set (D3) that contains points on the line segments defined by D1 (segment end-points), that minimizes error to the relative shape of D2.

Help me internet, you're my only hope :D

Edit:
Here is a 2D sketch of what I'm attempting to describe and solve in 3D..[sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mszKE.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you understand what you are asking?

Comment: Can you edit a example of data in order to make clear your problem ? What kind of problem of piecewise regression is it ? Are the segments linear or of different shapes ? Your question is too wide, not specific enough. They are a lot of different problems of this kind. For example see :  https://fr.scribd.com/document/380941024/Regression-par-morceaux-Piecewise-Regression-pdf

Comment: @JJacquelin: I edited the post with a sketch of what I'm trying to describe. The segments are linear. I need to determine the coordinates for D3. I hope this helps clarify.

Comment: I was asking for a numerical example, not for a symbolic description. For piecewise linear regressions see the document referenced in my previous comment. They are a lot of examples in various cases. May be one of them corresponds to what you are looking for.